# OWA error: Sorry, there was a problem and we can't open this document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, owa

I am not able to open Word documents using Office Web Apps. When trying to open it I'm getting this error-

[image]

I have run ULS logs on OWA server.

ULS Logs-

> WOPICheckFile,WACSERVER BadRequest [current url:http://server:43616/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/678676d7d0b1410b866f089695bf2481?access_token=REDACTED_1050&access_token_ttl=1472504532529]
>
> WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [exception:Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.FileUnknownException: WOPI 400
>    at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.GetWopiRequestResultWithRetry(Int32 maxSize, MemoryStream ms, WopiRequest wopiRequest)
>    at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()]
>
> WOPI CheckFile: Catch-All Failure [url:http://server:43616/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/678676d7d0b1410b866f089695bf2481]

Comment: Is it for SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It is SharePoint 2013

Comment: Hi Kamalpreet, install latest service pack for OWA and then try. We were also facing similar kind if issue, installing latest service pack resolved that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running Office Web Apps farm 2013 (which is very different from Office Web Apps 2010).

Run the PowerShell script `Get-OfficeWebAppsMachine` and see the output healthy/unhealthy

[image]

If it's healthy, you can see whether you allow HTTP or HTTPS requests to you OWA-farm by running

`Get-SPWOPIZone`

If you require HTTPS you can still test HTTP and see if there may be the SSL that's causing your problem. Set HTTP by running

`Set-SPWOPIZone - zone "internal-http"`

Comment: It is Healthy..

Comment: @Kamalpreet Good. Do you allow HTTP or do you require HTTPS

Comment: requires HTTPS..

Comment: @Kamalpreet I've edited the answer. You could try running HTTP and see if that works. Then your problem is narrowed to SSL and possably the certificate and/or trust

Comment: Now documents are opening in desktop application. We need to use OWA.

Comment: @Kamalpreet In the library settings > advanced. Set "Open in browser" and save https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/Learning/Articles/Pages/SharePoint-2013--change-how-office-files-open-by-default.aspx

Comment: In my case status shows Unhealthy and i am using external-https, this online document feature was working fine before but now it giving error mentioned in the main question

Comment: I have the same error and documents cant be edited in browser and i changed the WOPI zone to Http and now i can make the changes and save them via the desktop app.

Comment: Is it ok to use http internally (is it safe to use?? )

Comment: @AIM4DREAM If you have a firewall protecting your LAN, it is.

Comment: So is it safe to use http internally ? and everytime i open the document thats popping up a auth window asking for ID and password. is there a way to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Another case is just encountered where it shows the same error but its due to a recent update by Microsoft.

A recent [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3172457/ms17-014-description-of-the-security-update-for-office-web-apps-server) in OWA 2013 created an issue with SharePoint 2013 where it do not work with the sites or the files path that have spaces in their URLs. For example,

**OWA will work:** http://webapplication/sites/subsite/WithoutSpace

**OWA will not work:** http://webapplication/sites/subsite/With Space

Microsoft has recently released its patch on April 11, 2017 for SharePoint on this issue. Apply below patch (be patience if you don't see anything happening on the screen for couple of minutes) on all SharePoint servers only (not OWA ones).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3178732/april-11-2017-update-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013-kb3178732

Hope that will help someone.

**Source:** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bd7da9fb-eff7-418b-9263-c19b25c1b65c/office-web-apps-server-2013-march-2017-update?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself. The actual error was on the IIS website. It was set to redirect to https from http. Removing this setting worked in my case.

Comment: In my case status shows Unhealthy and i am using external-https, this online document feature was working fine before but now it giving error mentioned in the main question

Answer (score 0):

I have clarification for the main question. When i changed My SharePoint server TLS 1.0 protocol to 0 , i got this document error issue as soon as i changed it to 1(Enabled TLS1.0) in registry settings it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

in my case added our URL (https://myapplication.domain.com) under "Default" section in Alternate Access mapping, performed IIS reset in all servers. Post that the documents are loading fine.